# Java repeat during test

Tags: java, selenium, testing, random, cucumber

I have test in Ibello & Java. I use

```
int random = (int)(Math.random() * (100000 - 1) + 1);
```

To generate a 5 digit code.

I have a test class:

```
pthUgyintezesNewCase.I_Use_the_5digits();

allatiMellektermekSteps.Delete_the_old_datas();

pthNewCase.I_Save_And_Close(); //it brokes here

// Steps Class

public void I_Use_the_5digits() throws Exception{
        int random = (int)(Math.random() * (100000 - 1) + 1);

//
```

The app dont running if it generates the 5-digit number than ever. And Is it possible, than if it generates the seem again, it add 1 to a number until it can run?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the problem you're facing? It's a bit tough to understand what you're trying to explain

Comment: maybe now? i rewrited

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to generate a 5 digit number, but some times the number is only 4 digits? If this is the case, then try the following:

```
(int)(Math.random() * (100000 - 10000) + 10000);
```

by using 10000 instead of 1, you ensure that the number will always contain at least 5 digits

EDIT:

Here's a test case that checks the next 10'000'000 numbers:

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.Random;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        int number = (int)(Math.random() * (100000 - 10000) + 10000);
        if(String.valueOf(number).length() != 5) {
            System.out.println(String.valueOf(number).length());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Finished with all 5 digit numbers");
  }
}
```